# How does gitlab server handles http request

Tags: http, gitlab

I am wondering that how does gitlab server handles http request. Because, when I setup gitlab server without any http server. Is gitlab use node js etc. to handles http request?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Omnibus version, it is shipped, amongst others, with [nginx](http://nginx.org/), which is the webserver software it uses.

If you do not install the Omnibus versions, you can hook it up to your existing webserver.